# why Tabula giving same tables multiple times when converted PDF to JSON/CSV/TSV

Tags: jupyter, python-3.8, data-conversion, tabula, pdf-extraction

I am using below code to extract a table from a PDF, returned output is right. But at times, tabula is printing multiple same table multiple times which then in turn hampers the analysis. Any luck ?

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("stest2.pdf", pages='2', multiple_tables=False, guess=False)

b = tabula.convert_into("stest2.pdf", "stest.csv", output_format="csv",pages='2')
```

I have tried using area param but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but was able to fix it by opening the file and passing bytes to tabula instead of the path and removing the pages option entirely. Unsure of why this worked better. A possible workaround could be to process all pages and then select the data you want after that or use another library to select the page and then pass that to tabula

```
with open("stest2.pdf", "rb") as fp:
    tabula.read_pdf(fp, multiple_tables=False, guess=False)
```